# Windows Service not able to access a file in VB.net in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows, vb.net, web-services

I have a .net Windows Service developed in VB.net. I have a settings file in the root directory called Connections.XML and I am setting the basedirectory as below

```
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)

 Dim _path As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
                        Dim file As String = Path.Combine(_path, "Connections.xml")
```

When I schedule the service this is working absolutely fine in my Windows XP machine. But when I installed the same service in our development server (Windows 2003 64 bit Server) for some reason it is not able to locate this file.

Is there anything I am missing? Appreciate if you can help me out with this.

Thanks and have a good one.

Comment: What's the error message that you are getting?  Do you have any logging enabled in the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the user account that the service runs under have appropriate access permissions to the file and its path?